# Process generated DOM code using jquery after $http Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the next problem:
Im trying to access and modify the dom generated html by angular after I make a request using $http method.

Example:

```
    function Player($scope, $http) {

    var $player = $(".player");
    var _this = this;
    var playing = false;
    console.log('pepe');
    // Getting Songs
    $http.get('http://www.undert.com/components/player/js/songs.json').success(function (data) {

        $scope.songs = data.songs;
        console.log($player.find('li').length);

    });
}
```

and the HTML is:

```
   <div class="player" ng-controller="Player">
    <ul class="playlist">
        <li ng-repeat="song in songs">
            <div class="album-art">
                <div ng-show="!song.image">
                    <img src="http://undert.com/components/player/img/album_default.jpg" alt="{song.band}" />
                </div>
                <div ng-show="song.image">
                    <img src="http://undert.com/artists/{song.namespace}/images/albums/{song.image}" alt="{song.album}" />
                </div>
            </div> <a class="reproduction"></a>
 <a class="close"></a>
 <span class="title">{song.title}</span>
 <span class="artist">{song.artist}</span>

            <audio src="http://undert.com/artists/{song.namespace}/music/{song.song}"></audio>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="play"></div>
        <div class="prev"></div>
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I try to read my generated code inside

```
<li ng-repeat="song in songs">
```

using jquery I cant (It doesnt exists yet, but im trying to do that inside "success" callback on $http method).
This work perfectly when I dont use $http and make  the jsqon hardcoded inside my Player function.

thanks

Comment: try to put $scope.$apply() after   $scope.songs = data.songs;

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal I am pretty certain `Player` is the controller here which means that you don't have to add `$scope.$apply()` - you are already in the digest cycle...

Comment: Can you let us know what you need the code inside the `ng-repeat` directive construct? Maybe you don't need jQuery for it...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use $timeout like this:

```
$timeout(function(){ console.log($player.find('li').length); });
```

This will basically make your call happen only once Angular has finished generating the new DOM structure. Also $timeout has to be injected in the controller just like $http so your controller declaration should lokk like:

```
function Player($scope, $http, $timeout) {
```